# Getting friends on facebook's scores from parse

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, parse-platform

So I finally got my app letting users sign into Facebook and parse. Lets call my app a game even though it isn't and lets say that I upload the newest score someone gets every time they play the game. So what I have done is uploaded the "score" to parse under the user. Now, I want the user to be able to see friends that are on Facebook's score. So, I have the user signed in and now how can I check if their friend is using my "game" and then match their email with the one on parse to get there score? As of now, I can get the friends id's of the user that signed in.

BTW. the user has to sign into facebook and make a parse account for my app

I know I am gong to have to use a query to get stuff from parse, I guess my main question is **How do I get the facebook users email?**

This is how I am getting their id :

```
- (void)getFacebookInfo {
    [FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // Set user's information
            NSString *facebookId = [result objectForKey:@"id"];
            NSString *facebookName = [result objectForKey:@"name"];

            if (facebookName && facebookName.length != 0) {
                [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:facebookName forKey:@"displayName"];
            }
            if (facebookId && facebookId.length != 0) {
                [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:facebookId forKey:@"facebookId"];
            }

            [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                // Get user's friend information
                [FBRequestConnection startForMyFriendsWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                    if (!error) {
                        NSArray *data = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
                        NSMutableArray *facebookIds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:data.count];
                        for (NSDictionary *friendData in data) {
                            [facebookIds addObject:[friendData objectForKey:@"id"]];
                        }

                        [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:facebookIds forKey:@"facebookFriends"];
                        [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                            // We're in!
                            NSLog(@"%@", facebookName);
                            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
                        }];
                    } else {
                        [self showErrorAlert];
                    }
                }];
            }];
        } else {
            [self showErrorAlert];
        }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the email address of the Facebook user within the completion handler of `startForMyFriendsWithCompletionHandler` use:

```
[FBRequestConnection startForMyFriendsWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        NSArray *data = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
        for (NSDictionary *friendData in data) {

            //This is each friend's email address
            NSString *aFriendsEmail = [friendData objectForKey:@"email"];

        }
    }
}];
```

Comment: It logs null when I try to log aFriendsEmail. However, it logs other information, but I still will need an email. Is there another way?

Comment: What happens when you log "friendData" eg NSLog(@"%@", friendData); ?

Comment: I get a lot of information like username and user id. But i need their email.